# OpenAPI generator maven plugin - How to define Custom Path

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, code-generation, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using OpenAPI generator maven plugin with 6.4.0 version. I am facing two issue.

1. in swagger file server url defined and when i generate the code then @RequestMapping have base path with server url but i don't want to this path and also can not change swagger file.
2. I don't want to use test folder created from generated code. below are the properties I have using.

   ```
     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution-services</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>src/main/resources/openapi/services_swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                                <apiPackage>com.example.api</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>com.example.model</modelPackage>
                                <generateTestCode>false</generateTestCode>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                            </configOptions>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <java11>true</java11>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
   ```

Comment: which value do you take for comparison?

Comment: PRICE_CODE1, modelCode

Comment: which `PRICE_CODE1`?

Comment: in the above JSON PRICE_CODE1 is the key inside the price array.
comparing the object one

Comment: yes, i know. but which one do you take for comparing object one and two?

Comment: JSON is a text format. You cannot use `sort` to sort JSON, because it's text.  There is no need to invoke the JSON moniker for any set of data.

Comment: but my data is not a JSON object it is array,

Comment: modelId1 and modelId2

Comment: Your data is an array of objects, each of which has a property which is also an array of objects. None of that has anything to do with JSON.

Comment: I would recommend changing the structure of your data. It makes no sense to have an array of objects, each with a different key. I would flatten that array to an object, like `price: { PRICE_CODE1: <value>, PRICE_CODE2: <value>, PRICE_CODE3: <value> }`, then sorting would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This would work for the price array structure you have but not for modelCode as sort key.

```js
const data = [
   {
      "modelId":2,
      "modelCode":"model2",
      "price":[
         {
            "PRICE_CODE1":100.01
         },
         {
            "PRICE_CODE2":200.68
         },
         {
            "PRICE_CODE3":300.0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "modelId":1,
      "modelCode":"model1",
      "price":[
         {
            "PRICE_CODE1":225.01
         },
         {
            "PRICE_CODE2":247.68
         },
         {
            "PRICE_CODE3":298.0
         }
      ]
   }
]

function sortData(sortKeys = []) {
  data.sort((a,b) => {
    for (let sortKey of sortKeys) {
      const priceObjA = a.price.find(x => sortKey in x);
      const priceObjB = b.price.find(x => sortKey in x);
      const priceA = priceObjA && priceObjA[sortKey] || 0;
      const priceB = priceObjB && priceObjB[sortKey] || 0;
      const result = priceA - priceB;
      if (result !== 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    // fallback for equality
    return 0;
  })
}


sortData(['PRICE_CODE1']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));

sortData(['PRICE_CODE2']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));

sortData(['PRICE_CODE3']);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

> arr.sort(sortByMultipleKey(['PRICE_CODE1','modelCode']))

Your `sortByMultipleKey` takes a list of keys, each of which describe *one* key.  That can't describe the `PRICE_CODE1` field of an object under `prices`.

You're essentially trying to come up with a syntax to describe arbitrary location in hierarchical data.

Instead of doing that,  Use Javascript itself to define how to find the next comparison field!  pass functions that can resolve the fields and iterate over those.

Below, I will define 2 functions.  The first will extract the first `PRICE_CODE1` from the elements of `prices`.

```
  function(d) {
    for (i = 0; i < d.price.length; d++) {
      if ("PRICE_CODE1" in d.price[i]) {
        return d.price[i].PRICE_CODE1
      }
    }
    return undefined
  }
```

The one for modelCode is simpler:

```
  function(d) {
    return d.modelCode
  }
```

I also add a 3rd model with the same `PRICE_CODE1` so that `modelCode` would also be relevant.

```js
function sortByMultiple(field_funcs) {
  return function(a, b) {
    for (i = 0; i < field_funcs.length; i++) {
      fa = field_funcs[i](a)
      fb = field_funcs[i](b)
      console.log("Comparing " + fa + " and " + fb)
      if (fa < fb) return -1;
      if (fa > fb) return 1;
      if (i + 1 == field_funcs.length) return 0
    }
  }
}
var data = [{
    "modelId": 2,
    "modelCode": "model2",
    "price": [{
        "PRICE_CODE1": 100.01
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE2": 200.68
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE3": 300.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "modelId": 1,
    "modelCode": "model1",
    "price": [{
        "PRICE_CODE1": 225.01
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE2": 247.68
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE3": 298.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "modelId": 3,
    "modelCode": "model3",
    "price": [{
        "PRICE_CODE1": 225.01
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE2": 247.68
      },
      {
        "PRICE_CODE3": 298.0
      }
    ]
  }
]

data.sort(sortByMultiple([
  function(d) {
    for (i = 0; i < d.price.length; d++) {
      if ("PRICE_CODE1" in d.price[i]) {
        return d.price[i].PRICE_CODE1
      }
    }
    return undefined
  },
  function(d) {
    return d.modelCode
  }
]))
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash library:

```
_.orderBy( data, [c => c.price[0].PRICE_CODE1, "modelCode"], ["asc", "asc"]);
```

Comment: Hey, don't you think, this will first sort wrt to `PRICE_CODE1` and then wrt `modelCode`. At last, by your method, **the array will be sorted only based on `last parameter`, the previous sorting will not have any effect.**

Comment: Hi Himanshu, You're right. It's modified.